# map degrees to 0 - 360 in python

Tags: python, mapping, degrees

is it possible to map a value of rotation to be inside the range of 0-360 degrees?

For example:

- a angle of -10° should be 350°
- a angle of 760° should be 40° degrees?

Is there an easy solution? Maybe in mathutils?

best,
chris

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use the modulo operator `%` for this:

```
>>> print -10 % 360
350
>>> print 760 % 360
40
```

Comment: Hi Juanchopanza,

thank you very much! This is exactly what i was looking for.

Best,
Chris

Comment: also thanks from me..very helpful